# Translation string does not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use rails 2.3.5 and have in my locale file this line:

```
more_in_category: "Mehr aus der Kategorie '{{category}}'"
```

and in my view:

```
<%= t 'more_in_category', :category=>@topic_category.title %>
```

On production everything works fine. The String is replaced with the content of the category title, but on my local/development the category is not replaced. It prints out the some like I wrote in the locale file.

> "Mehr aus der Kategorie
>   '{{category}}'"

any ideas what I miss?

Comment: Found some extra problem: on my dev there was the i18n gem installed. I removed it and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a newer version of Ruby in your development environment. If you use Rails version 2.3.8 or less then you can't use Ruby 1.9.

Edit:

You could try to use %{...} instead of {{...}}

Comment: I use locale ruby-1.8.7-p24 (rvm) and the dev/local server is 2.3.5 


=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000

Comment: Hmm, that seems strange. I also have an environment with rails 2.3.5 and ruby 1.8.7 and it works properly but I see the following in console: "The {{key}} interpolation syntax in I18n messages is deprecated. Please use %{key} instead."

Comment: @DanneManne, it's polite to check other answers before submitting the same answer in your comments...

Comment: I agree, but I don't seem to remember getting any notification about anybody else submitting an answer before my edit as I usually do when that happens. I assure you that my answer was not a copy but an analyse for the question

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here. Have you tried this:

```
more_in_category: "Mehr aus der Kategorie %{category}"
```